# Jquery function cannot be found

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

I've been having problems with Jquery Datetime picker. The slider wouldn't work on touch devices. Luckily the solution has since been found and [Implemented](http://trentrichardson.com/2011/12/05/add-ui-slider-accessibility-to-timepicker/)

But updating the Jquery datetimepicker code, is giving me the error:

```
$tp.find(".ui-slider:visible").sliderAccess is not a function
```

This is coming from the Jquery Datetime picker file itself, so is not code I have written.

The only logical thing I can think of is, I'm missing a dependancy? But there is no mention for one.

```
$(".dateTimePicker").datetimepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' , addSliderAccess: true, sliderAccessArgs: { touchonly: false} }); // dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
$(".datePicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', showButtonPanel: true }); // dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
$(".timePicker").timepicker({ stepMinute: 5, addSliderAccess: true, sliderAccessArgs: { touchonly: false} });
```

Does anyone know what Im doing wrong.

Comment: mmh your mvc3/.net tags is kindda dodgy

Comment: Can you pop it into a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for us?

Comment: think you are missing the jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you including all of the .js files? Looking at the source code of [example](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) page you can see it's including

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yea, that would be a problem :). Missed out the slider access addon. I assumed it was part of the datepicker addon code, Since it calls functions from within it. Obtained the slideraccess.js via source code. I dont know where the actual download is supose to be O.o A link for others, and future reference would be nice. Cheers!

Comment: Link is on the example page (but I don't think it's obvious enough) [download from the original site](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js)

Comment: Lifesaver! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For convenience, this is where you can get that jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js file.  It's non-obvious from the actual project page where to get this.

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/js/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js

Answer (score 0):

As @CCBlackburn is saying, you are missing the slider include

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>
```

I would also recommend to download from the github website, Click on the Zip button with a Cloud on it and arrow:

https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon